# Defining a block of scoped global variables in C++

Tags: c++, class, c++11, namespaces, thread-safety

I am writing code where I need a block of globals, say, `Param` that is accessible to all the other header `*.hpp/.h` and the `*.cpp` files. Theses globals need to be initialized in the beginning and can be changed throughout the code run. There also needs to be a single instance of the block and all contents are shared. All the contents need to be `global`.

What is the best possible way to implement it? A `namespace Param{};` or a `class Param{};`- with all the members declared static?

Also, how would we make some constants in the block `thread_local` (best practice)?

Comment: *"Theses constants [..] can be changed"*. So there are not constant, just globals.

Comment: @Jarod42 Sorry, for the confusion. I have edited the question. They are globals.

Comment: Are you looking for a Singleton? Use a class and a free function returning a reference to a local static instance. "*Also, how would we make some constants in the block thread_local*" In that case scratch that and rethink your design, that will be a total mess.

Comment: I suggest rethinking the need for a "block of globals" *at all*. It is a flawed go-to thought when someone wants to get to the coding rather than "wasting" time in design - i.e. provide all source files access to the global data. However, as the program gets more features, more data needs to be in the "block of globals" and managing it consumes more and more time (e.g. it is challenging to debug when some global data is unexpectedly changing, because all source files are potential culprits). People who think "oh that's okay - the program won't grow that much" are usually proven wrong over time

Comment: I am working on a simulation of a physical system and I definitely need a block of globals shared by multiple classes and translation units. I can't think of any other way (suggestions are welcome).

Comment: @Quimby I can create a separate Param Space for thread_local variables say `Param_Thread`, but how should I implement them?

Comment: @Quimby Would a class with all static variables not be the same as a Singleton, with a lifetime of the whole program?

Comment: @Yatharth Well, yes, but static initialization across compilation units is unspecified. So, you could not use these values to initialize anything else that is static. Static local variables are the safest, thread-safe option. Yes, splittng them into two Singletons (thread-local and global) would be the safest. Do not forget to protect the write-access to the globals. But seriously, the idea is really bad. I would at least suggest to wrap them in getters, setters. That way you could more easily track the access and debug.

Comment: @Quimby That would not be a problem since all values will be initialised seperately and can be changed accordingly during the run.But would such an approach scale accordingly if the values are declared `thread_local` ? And how can I do the same with a `namespace` instead of a `class` with all variables static?

Comment: Why do you want `namespace`? Initialization is thread-safe because they are initialized before main. How are you planning on ensuring proper locking with exposed globals?Scale? W.r.t to number of threads - just fine. W.r.t to maintability - not at all. You are digging yourself a hole with this approach. Out of curiosity what kind of global does your simulation need?

Comment: @Quimby Variables like timestep, Thermodynamic variables like Pressure, Particle Count, Boundary of box that could change within a single thread but would be shared by multiple classes.

Comment: @Quimby Would variables declared in a namespace not be initialised before main? What if I explicitly initialise them in the namespace? (I don't know.)

Comment: Yes, there are initialized before main, so that is fine. That sound to me like there should be a clear owner of these variables, so store them inside it and provide an interface for reading them.

Comment: @Quimby Add parse through a file (like JSON)?

Comment: No, that is not what I mean. Just that they would be ordinary members of some `Manager` class which would have `get_XXX` methods.

Comment: @Quimby How would the user initialise them? Assuming some 10-15 parameters? Like this? -> Just by declaring in a *CPP file `int static Param::VarX = 0.00;`?

Comment: Sure, but you probably meant `double`. You should consult some tutorials or literature on working with `static`s, it's not exactly an unknown area.